# Is there a tool which shows which keyboard buttons are pressed?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Is there a tool which indicates, at driver-level or kernel-level, which keys on the keyboard are pressed at any moment?

(Problem: I suspect the Print Screen button on my keyboard is not working. I want to positively confirm that it is a hardware issue. Also works for diagnosing F1-F12 keys or other function keys.)

Comment: In case it's relevant, is it a USB or PS/2 keyboard? Would a Linux live-CD do the job?

Comment: @grawity It's the a Microsoft wireless keyboard with a USB connector. I wouldn't mind Linux, though I'm skeptical about MS's compatibility though... (some of their mouse and keyboard *requires* Win8/10 and won't even work on Win7!)

Answer (score 0):

#### Linux

If you have a Linux system available (liveCD/USB will do), you can use tools to see the *evdev* key events. They are after kernel processing (not raw USB scancodes), but before any userspace processing.

Microsoft wireless devices should work.

1. Install the *evemu* or *evemu-tools* package.
2. In a terminal, run `sudo evemu-record` to get a list of recognized input devices.
3. Enter the device's number. (Also possible to provide the /dev path directly in step 2.)
4. Press various keys and watch events. (The monitoring is not exclusive, so the same events will continue reaching the rest of the OS – e.g. if you press PrintScr, it will show up in evemu-record *and* will make a screenshot.)
5. Kill the program with Ctrl+C.

Alternatively, to see "raw scancodes" (not *entirely* raw, but reasonably close):

1. Check whether you already have the *kbd* package.
2. Use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to access a plain non-X11 console. (If you don't find one at F2, try F3, F4, F5…)
3. Run `showkey --scancodes`.
4. Press some keys. Everything will be intercepted by the showkey program. You will see a line for each keypress or release, with variable amount of scancodes. (I **don't** know whether they're straight from USB, or whether they're translated to AT / PS/2 equivalents.)
5. To exit, stop pressing things and wait 10 seconds.

#### Windows

Didn't find anything. Most programs show processed key codes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I needed to find out which device or program triggers a "button pressed" state.

The only nearly helpful tool on Windows I found is ["KeyboardStateView" from NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/keyboard_state_view.html).

A website which shows pressed keys with focus on an input field is [here](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html).